# Cannot shutdown the host when QEMU/KVM is installed

Tags: shutdown, libvirt

I have a problem with LIBVIRT or something. The host is Linux Fedora 34 on AMD and the guest VM is Windows 10. Virt-manager is connected through user session. I am fairly new to Linux, but I recently switched to QEMU/KVM from Virtualbox and guest VM itself is working fine.

My problem is that every time I want to reboot or shutdown my host system, first stop job for Virtualization daemon is running for about 6 minutes and then shutdown sequence finishes but my host computer does not power down or reboots itself as used to and I have to hold down the power button to turn off host machine.

I tried to shutdown the guest VM before host shutdown but with no luck. Secondly, whenever I stop libvirtd.service in linux I just cannot restart it without completely rebooting my host computer.

What to do?

Comment: For testing purposes, go inside the VM and shut it down.  It's possible it is not receiving the shutdown command if you issue it from libvirt/qemu.  Then try to shut down your host.  If the vm hangs on shutdown, it will hold the host during the shutdown process.

Perhaps the windows computer is installing updates.  This can take more than 6 minutes.

Comment: Thank you, I did that. I shutdown VM from inside, that is from Windows, then I close virt-manager on host and start host shutdown process. Libvirt daemon is stopping for 6 minutes then seems finished but host is not powering down.

Comment: This is the kind of situation where there's a small misconfiguration, and the errors don't lead you to it.  Sometimes the best thing to do is to rebuild the hypervisor host.  Make appropriate backups and so forth first, of course.